# LibGDX how to make a buttons size independent of image

Tags: libgdx

When adding images to a TextButton in LibGDX how would I match the button to the contents of the image. Currently when I set size the image scales down to fit the button which leaves a large gap between the edge of the button and the contents of the image (See distance from green debug border to the edge of the buttons image).

I would like to be able to set the size of the button to match the content of the image so that the empty space around the image is ignored. I could crop out the empty space from the image but would have an off centered image due to the drop shadow and so would like to avoid that.

[image]

Top image shows the displayed dutton in game including the debug button border in green. Bottom image shows the source image with empty space.

```
TextButton.TextButtonStyle buttonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
buttonStyle.font = FontLoader.uiFont;
buttonStyle.up = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(assetManager.get(UISpriteLoader.SPRITE_UI_TAMING_BUTTON_BASE, Texture.class)));
buttonStyle.down = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(assetManager.get(UISpriteLoader.SPRITE_UI_TAMING_BUTTON_PRESSED, Texture.class)));
buttonStyle.over = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(assetManager.get(UISpriteLoader.SPRITE_UI_TAMING_BUTTON_HOVER, Texture.class)));
tameButton = new TextButton("Tame", buttonStyle);
tameButton.setPosition(1470, 1080-330-80);
tameButton.setSize(250, 80);
stage.addActor(tameButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Ninepatch for your images. It will scale to fill the button out of the box.

I recommend you to use [Skin Composer](https://ray3k.wordpress.com/software/skin-composer-for-libgdx/) both for making the Ninepatches and for creating a Scene2d skin so you don't have to create your Styles in code.

Comment: Good idea but I don't think I could recreate the border gradient in a nine patch.